# Find the odds against drawing zero diamonds

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working on the following problem:

> What are the odds against drawing no diamond in a $2$-fold draw from a
>   full pack with replacement?

My solution:

$(\frac{13}{52})^2 = (\frac{1}{4})^2 = \frac{1}{16}$ are the chances of drawing diamonds

$1 -  (\frac{1}{16}) = \frac{15}{16}$ are the chances of drawing no diamonds.

So the odds against drawing no diamonds are:
$1:15$

But my notes say: $9:7$

What is wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 3):

Your $\frac{1}{16}$ is the probability for *both* cards to be diamonds, and so $1-\frac{1}{16}= \frac{15}{16}$ is the probability of drawing 1 diamond or no diamonds at all between the two cards.

To draw no diamonds at all, you simply get $\frac{39}{52} \cdot\frac{39}{52} = \frac{3}{4} \cdot\frac{3}{4}=\frac{9}{16}$

Hence the probability of drawing 1 or more diamonds is $1-\frac{9}{16}=\frac{7}{16}$

Comment: For clarification, a **probability** of $\frac{7}{16}$ corresponds to the **odds** of $7:9$ in favor of or as requested $9:7$ against.  (*Personally... I dislike the whole notion of using odds instead of probability, but it remains a part of some of our modern culture*)

Comment: @JMoravitz .. which is exactly why I didn't even translate it into odds :)

Comment: @JMoravitz: Since the odds against drawing no diamonds are the odds in favor of drawing diamons why is it not $7:9$ the answer?

Comment: @Jim Good question ... I'm with JMoravitz ... phrasing probabilities in terms of 'odds for' or 'odds against' often leads to confusion.

Comment: @Bram28: I don't have any reason to support otherwise on that point, but I would be interested at least to understand the solution in this case or to know if it is a "typo"

Comment: @Jim I am sure it is a 'typo'. That, or the fact that you have two negations here ('against' and 'no'), which adds to the confusion.